# Prevent multiple instances of my Android application composed of a single activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an Android application which is composed from a single `Activity`.
How can I assure that only one instance of my application (== `Activity`) will exist in a given time?
I got to a situation in which I succeeded to open multiple instances of my app by clicking on the app icon multiple times (this doesn't reproduce all the time).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

change your manifest like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.yourpackage.YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

include the `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and it will not be possible to have multiple instances of your Activity launched at the same time. [See the activity docs for more.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: is it preferred over `"singleInstance"`?

Comment: read the difference between the two in the docs and decide which one fits your use case better... Without knowing anything more about your application I can't answer that.

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask" not working 
android:launchMode="singleInstance" works

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It's 2022 and I was facing the same issue where I implemented an app theme changing dialog box and every time when I relaunched the app (making sure that it was not in the RECENTS before opening it i.e. it is not running in the background), a new instance of the same activity used to create when the current theme did not match with the device's default theme and I tried a lot of methods to correct it, but nothing worked. Finally, I found this, and my issue is resolved now. Btw, both "singleTask" and "singleInstance" worked for me. : )

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer serves its purpose, but it is not the best way to do this.

Instead, I recommend using a static `AtomicInteger` inside of each of your activities like so:

```
//create a counter to count the number of instances of this activity
public static AtomicInteger activitiesLaunched = new AtomicInteger(0);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {

        //if launching will create more than one 
        //instance of this activity, bail out
        if (activitiesLaunched.incrementAndGet() > 1) { finish(); }

        super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

        //remove this activity from the counter
        activitiesLaunched.getAndDecrement();

        super.onDestroy();

}
```

### So, what's wrong with the accepted answer?

Declaring that your activity should be launched using the `singleInstance` mode starts messing with the default behavior for activities and tasks, which can have some unwanted effects.

The [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) recommend that you only disrupt this behavior when it's necessary (it's not in this case):

> Caution: Most applications should not interrupt the default behavior for >activities and tasks. If you determine that it's
>   necessary for your activity to modify the default behaviors, use
>   caution and be sure to test the usability of the activity during
>   launch and when navigating back to it from other activities and tasks
>   with the Back button. Be sure to test for navigation behaviors that
>   might conflict with the user's expected behavior.

Comment: Is the solution you propose supposed to work on apps with multiple Activities? I'm ending up with a blank Activity and in some scenarios the app won't start at all.

Comment: It should. That is what I was using it for with no issue. Granted, that was a couple years ago... Is it possible that you have issues elsewhere in your code? Try to eliminate that possibility: Start a new project with two basic activities that only display text ("Activity 1" & "Activity 2") . Then implement this method & test in this control environment to see if it still gives you weird issues like that.

Comment: My use-case is to start my app from any 3rd party app with Intent.ACTION_VIEW action, while my app runs in background. Right, I will try it on some trivial code to see if it can work.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck solving your problem?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The singleTop launchMode caused a lot of problems in my app while receiving notifications.

Comment: This answer solved my problem! Forgot about atomic integer for this purpose, this works fantastic

Comment: Maybe I did this wrong, but this does not seem to prevent it be launched via an outside intent (i.e. opening an app URL)

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 I don't know if you did anything wrong because I don't know if the results you're getting are expected. I never tried doing that, but I would find it very surprising that launching the app from a URL changes the method in which its launched so drastically that this method no longer works.

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 Does this method work for you when not launching via an outside intent?

Comment: @HunterS As in, starting the main activity via an intent from the main activity? I'm using jetpack compose so I only have a single activity, so my use case may be niche (for now at least)

Answer (score 0):

I've found users of my app have been running out of memory and I was struggling to work out why. While trying to do so I found I could open multiple instances of my app my repeatedly clicking the icon then Home, then the icon, then Home.. I could see the memory use going up and up until eventually the app crashed. Before it crashed I could click the Close menu option and the previous instance came to the front, this would happen as many times as I'd launched the app.

My solution was to add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the manifest. Since then I've been unable to open more than one instance or crash the app.