# Android tablet multiple instances of application

Tags: android, single-instance

I am using Android tablet to test my application.

- I press the home button to put the application to background.

Now, if

- I launch the application from recent apps, it will open the same
  screen, I was on, and will not restart the application.
- But, if I launch the application from my apps, it starts a new
  instance of application. This time it restarts the application
  from splash screen, and when I check the recent apps, it shows
  2 instances of my app.

I want only one instance of the application to be running, on my tablet, at any time. Please help...

Comment: This question was answered here:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693191/prevent-multiple-instances-of-my-android-application-composed-of-a-single-activi>

Comment: I have tried that answer. It disables multiple instances of application. But When I put the application in background, and launch it from applications on home screen, it restarts the application, instead of directly opening the screen it was on before going to background.