# getReferrer when activity is opened by a intent returns null

Tags: android, android-intent, referrer

I have an activity that has this intent in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mc8.eu"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If I receive an SMS with this scheme, the activity correctly is opened if I click the url.

What I need is to understand if the activity is opened by the intent or by another app activity.

I tried with this code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Uri ref = getReferrer();
}
```

But getReferrer always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Once the system starts your activity through an intent filter, you can use data provided by the Intent to determine what you need to render. Call the [getData()](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#handling-intents) and getAction() methods to retrieve the data and action associated with the incoming Intent

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
}
```

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#handling-intents)

Comment: `action` and `data` variable are both null

Comment: I will try, but what if I need that?

Comment: It worked, but I need to have just 1 instance of the activity. How can I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693191/prevent-multiple-instances-of-my-android-application-composed-of-a-single-activi