# Flutter App opens in another application(duplicate application)

Tags: flutter, applinks

I'm using **app links** with [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) library in my **flutter** app.

There is a problem that
whenever I clicked my app link in another application(like Google Calendar), the OS opens my app again.

Somehow I have a duplicate of that.
Here is my screenshot that what exactly happened:

[image: my screenshot]

I just want to open my last app that exists in background.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693417/4696843),

I should change `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to `android:launchMode="singleTask"` of my `MainActivity` in `manifest.xml`.

Comment: thanks that really helped me with the same problem ..

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me. It was driving my crazy.

Comment: How about for iOS applink?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links), for `android:launchMode="singleTask"` you have to use `_handleIncomingLinks` to receive new intents

```
StreamSubscription? _sub;
void _handleIncomingLinks() {
if (!kIsWeb) {
  // It will handle app links while the app is already started - be it in
  // the foreground or in the background.
  _sub = uriLinkStream.listen((Uri? uri) {
    if (!mounted) return;
    print('got uri: $uri');
    
  }, onError: (Object err) {
    if (!mounted) return;
    print('got err: $err');
  });
 }
}
```

If using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` you have to use `_handleInitialUri` to receive new intents

```
bool _initialUriIsHandled = false;


Future<void> _handleInitialUri() async {

if (!_initialUriIsHandled) {
  _initialUriIsHandled = true;
  try {
    if (!mounted) return;
    final uri = await getInitialUri();

    if (uri != null) {
      //todo
    }
  } on PlatformException {
    // Platform messages may fail but we ignore the exception
    print('falied to get initial uri');
  } on FormatException catch (err) {
    if (!mounted) return;
    print('malformed initial uri');
  }
 }
}
```

for more detail about methods check [this sample](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links/example)